# Getting PHP error when embedding Jquery/JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, parse-error

I am not actually particularly new to PHP or JQuery. That makes this error even stranger. Consider these two code samples. (Since I hacked them together in about five minutes for this post, they're simplistic and messy - but make the point.)

```
<?php
print<<<HERE
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1     /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-  ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<p>Error show</p>
<button id="targetbutton" style="height: 60px width: 100px">mouse in</button>
<script>
$("#targetbutton").mouseover(function() 
{$("p").css("color", "red")
});
</script>
HERE;
?>
```

and

```
<?php
print<<<HERE
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<p>Error show</p>
<button id="targetbutton" style="height: 60px width: 100px">mouse in</button>
<script>
/*
$("#targetbutton").mouseover(function() 
{$("p").css("color","red")
});
*/
</script>
HERE;
?>
```

Both these code blocks produce this error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in ... on line 11** 
(actually the second one says ...line 12 - obviously)

THIS code works:

```
<?php
print<<<HERE
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<p>Error show</p>
<button id="targetbutton" style="height: 60px width: 100px">mouse in</button>
<script>
$("#targetbutton").mouseover(function() {
$("p").css("color", "red")
});
</script>
HERE;
?>
```

As I mentioned, I put together this somewhat messy and simplistic example to make a point. However, I first saw the error in the well formatted web site I am creating - thus code beauty - or lack of such - doesn't seem to be the issue.) So three questions arise:
1. Why is PHP throwing errors about non-PHP code (line 11 is inside script tags)?
2. Why is PHP throwing errors about commented out code?
3. Why does the moving of a curly brace suddenly solve everything?
Since I got it working this question is epistemological, but interesting.

Comment: There is nothing strange here, it works as it is documented. Read about [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

In HEREDOC (and double-quoted strings), `{$` introduces an interpolated variable or expression.

If you want to dump stuff to the browser, either drop out of PHP mode entirely, or use NOWDOC:

```
print <<<'HERE'
Note single-quotes around keyword
You can now have anything you like here and PHP won't try
to mess with it.
HERE;
```

Comment: Wow... almost 10 years of PHP and never knew about {$ inside heredocs. Thanks!